# Firebase emulator: Firestore document listeners don't detach when browser tabs are closed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm working on a web app and developing against the Firebase emulator. Sometimes I'll open the app in multiple browser tabs to make sure that realtime data is updating properly, then I'll close them.

I was looking at the Firestore `Requests` tab and noticed a suspicious number of `GET` calls.  Every time I updated certain data, I'd see about 50 `GETs`.

After a moment of billing-related panic it turns out that these weren't caused by some mistake in my code but instead were coming from lingering `onSnapshot` listeners from the past week of development. I confirmed this by restarting the emulator, and voilà, I update the same data and the extra `GETS` are gone.

After a little testing it looks like document listeners aren't being detached when you close a browser tab or window. They just keep on running.

Is this a bug? Is there any way I can flush document listeners without restarting the emulator? (except doing it from within my app)

Comment: Without seeing [exact steps to reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard to say whether this is a bug. But if you think this is a bug, it's probably better to post an issue to the [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues) with those exact steps on how the maintainers can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks Frank, I was looking for a repo but didn't know which one to post in for the emulator. I'll try to put together a more specific reproducible example